# Arctext plugin code works only once on click

Tags: jquery, html, arctext.js

I am using Arctext jQuery plugin to curve the text in one of a div. The code works fine but it works only once I will have to refresh the page to make it work again. I don't know where the real problem is.

```html
<script src="arctext/js/jquery.arctext.js"></script>
<button class="mce-text">Curve</button>
<div class="shape ui-resizable" style="width:100px; height:100px" data-active="me">
  <div class="cut">&times;</div>
  <span class="show-cont" style="line-height: 1;"></span>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.mce-txt', function() {
  var show = $('.shape[data-active=me]');

  show.children('.show-cont').arctext({
    radius: 270,
    dir: -1,
    rotate: true,
    animation: {
      speed: 300
    }
  });
});
```

**UPDATE:**
here is the logic

http://prntscr.com/mbz705

Comment: What do you mean by 'make it work again'? Your code sample only initialises it once.

Comment: I said the code works only once, when page loads.

Comment: And as I said, you only initialise the plugin once, so what are you expecting to happen? Also, could you add a link to the plugin as all the ones I've found named 'arctext' do not have an `animation` property.

Comment: This is the link to their demo https://tympanus.net/Development/Arctext/ and you can see their code specifying animation property by viewing their source code.

Comment: If you're looking  at their source code you can see your syntax is wrong. You need to call the `set` option, providing an object which contains the settings to change to.

Comment: I followed their way too but in console I got an error saying "using method prior to initialization" even I initialized it and then used that 'set' method.

Comment: That's because you need to call the plugin once to set the initial state, then again using `set` to animate it - presumably under a click event.

Comment: I initialized the plugin and then on button click called the set method and got that error in console.

Comment: I've added an example for you below toi make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue you have is that you set the class as `.mce-text` in the HTML, yet in the jQuery selector you're using `.mce-txt`.

That aside, the logic is incorrect. The Arctext library requires you to initialise the library on an element with the default state. Then to animate it under the button click you need to call the library again with the `set` option along with an object detailing the new settings to animate. Try this:

```js
// set initial state
var $show = $('.shape[data-active=me]').arctext({
  radius: 300
});

// change state on button click
$(document).on('click', '.mce-text', function() {
  $show.arctext('set', {
    radius: 270,
    dir: -1,
    animation: {
      speed: 300
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.shape {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

.show-cont {
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://tympanus.net/Development/Arctext/js/jquery.arctext.js"></script>

<button class="mce-text">Curve</button>

<div class="shape ui-resizable" data-active="me">
  <div class="cut">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <span class="show-cont"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Still not working , but now getting no error in console and I need to display data in 'show-cont' class.

Comment: You need to update the question with the logic you're using then, as you can see from the example above it works when used correctly.

Comment: its 'mce-txt' in html and '.mce-txt' in jquery. It was a typing mistake when I wrote the question in here

Comment: I just added a screenshot to let you understand the flow

Comment: The screenshot doesn't really change anything. The above code works.

Comment: Ok thanks , I really appreciate you. Let me look for the critical logical errors, anyways thank you for being helpful.